# Checksum using 8 bit unsigned arithmetic in Python

Tags: python, checksum, unsigned, 8-bit

I'm having a heck of time trying to derive the checksum for my serial data. I received the data as bytes, removed the flags and escape characters, placed it in a list. The instruction document specifies with a graphic that the checksum is at the end of data structure. The checksum is calculated by summing all bytes in the Record using 8 bit unsigned arithmetic. Unfortunately, I have a huge data file:

```
[198, 2, 180, 4, 0, 0, 224, 253, 156, 94, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 22, 1, 1, 44, 2, 4, 189, 189, 255, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 224, 253, 156, 94, 51, 58, 0, 0, 0, 18, 2, 128, 10, 129, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 128, 2, 128, 2, 128, 1, 128, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 128, 2, 128, 2, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 3, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 4, 128, 3, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 4, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 1, 128, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 128, 2, 128, 2, 128, 1, 128, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 203, 29, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 38, 8, 38, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 255, 141, 2, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 173, 1, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 65, 0, 224, 253, 156, 94, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 2, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 4, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 73, 13, 0, 0, 176, 192, 0, 0, 226, 1, 0, 0, 198, 2, 0, 0, 240, 127, 170, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 49, 28, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 65, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 195, 165, 0, 0, 195, 165, 1, 128, 72, 8, 160, 15, 32, 78, 208, 7, 208, 7, 112, 23, 80, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 52, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 208, 7, 112, 23, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 178]
```

The last hexidecimal is 178 (0xB2) which I'm assuming is the checksum. When I apply checksum code I found online  it simple adds all the integers up which far exceeds '178'. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: If you sum using 8 bit unsigned arithmetic, it return 178 tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use:

```
l = [198, 2, 180, 4, 0, 0, 224, 253, 156, 94, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 22, 1, 1, 44, 2, 4, 189, 189, 255, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 189, 224, 253, 156, 94, 51, 58, 0, 0, 0, 18, 2, 128, 10, 129, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 128, 2, 128, 2, 128, 1, 128, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 128, 2, 128, 2, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 3, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 4, 128, 3, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 4, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 1, 128, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 128, 2, 128, 2, 128, 1, 128, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 203, 29, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 38, 8, 38, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 255, 141, 2, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 173, 1, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 65, 0, 224, 253, 156, 94, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 2, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 128, 1, 128, 4, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 1, 128, 73, 13, 0, 0, 176, 192, 0, 0, 226, 1, 0, 0, 198, 2, 0, 0, 240, 127, 170, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 49, 28, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 65, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 195, 165, 0, 0, 195, 165, 1, 128, 72, 8, 160, 15, 32, 78, 208, 7, 208, 7, 112, 23, 80, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 52, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 208, 7, 112, 23, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 178]

sum(l[:-1]) & 255
```

output:

```
178
```

8-bit overflow occurs in the binary sum so you keep only the last 8 bits from your sum